# How did the judge pay his barber?

Tags: lateral-thinking, enigmatic-puzzle

An Olympic judge rushes into the barbershop. "You need to help me!" he pleads. "I have to judge in 10 minutes, but I've been traveling so much I look just awful." The barber looks at him carefully. "Your hair is quite long. I'll need to cut it. And you'd look silly with a beard and such short hair. You're in luck, as I've just had a cancellation. Have a seat!"

The barber does his work and goes to collect the payment. "Oh dear," said the judge. "I haven't any local currency to pay you with." Luckily, he and the barber were able to work out a deal. The judge, having fully paid the barber, leaves to go judge his match.

On his lunch break, the barber was watching the Olympic games and sure enough there was the judge, attention gazed on the performers, looking for any mistakes he could find.

- Why was the judge looking for mistakes so intently?
- What was the deal between the barber and the judge?

Clarifications:

- The judge is an honorable judge. There is no foul play.
- The judge and the barber will never interact again. The deal is fully concluded in a mutually acceptable way.
- Nothing illegal is transpiring.
- Currency is not involved in any way.

Comment: Given that answers that fit are being ruled out with additional stipulations after the fact, and I expect this to continue, I'm voting to close as too broad.

Comment: All conditions are satisfied by this solution : Judge has free tickets to the event, and **he gave the ticket as payment for the Barber**. Judge was looking intently for mistakes because **that is what he has to do** [[[[ no foul play, honorable Judge, no more interaction, nothing illegal, no currency ]]]]

Comment: @Prem There is nothing lateral or enigmatic about somebody doing what they're supposed to do. I've been working on a better version of it that makes it a much more enjoyable puzzle.

Comment: Was the answer that the judge paid the barber with some currency other than the local currency?

Comment: Now I want to know what the answer to this lost gem is.

Comment: Oh sure, I remember this one. Here's a hint: the reason he was looking intently for mistakes was because awarding a perfect score would have been very difficult for him (as a direct result of his payment to the barber). It also would be useful to know (in hindsight) that both the barber and the judge were a little geeky.

Comment: @question_asker and if you give that a go and you still can't get it, this is a dead giveaway: http://imgur.com/FqW2eOz

Comment: @corsiKa Well I guess I have an idea what the payment could have been, though it seems a little spectacular, and I don't know how it fits in with that bit you linked to.

Comment: @corsiKa OK, maybe I don't get it. I get the impression this relies on some obscure interpretation of the implication of your linked image, one that I've never heard before. That, or I'll kick myself if I ever find out the answer.

Comment: @feelinferrety You're very warm. He definitely gives the barber something that he would have 'given' to an athlete. As a contender, what can't you receive if a judge notices a mistake?

Comment: Ah, sorry -- I had deleted my comment because I thought it would just trigger another "the judge is wholly beyond reproach" comment. I had originally suggested the judge gave the barber a bronze medal and judged so carefully in order to disqualify all but two competitors.  Anyway, the image posted denotes (hah) the ditty "Shave and a haircut -- two bits." The judge did indeed receive both. Still putting the two together.

Comment: So far I can only think that awarding a perfect score would require him to award a 10, which looks like binary for two and requires two bits to display...

Comment: I still want to know this one (I hinted at it in my above comment)

Comment: The comment above yours nailed it. He had the cards in his bag, and gave the guy the 10 card because, as everyone knows (or so I thought) a shave and a haircut costs two bits, for which a 1 and a 0 certainly fit the bill.

Comment: groan ... well better late than never, +1

Answer (score 10):

Hmm, very open ended question.

Only can come up with a fairly stupid guess:

> The barber shaved his shops name onto this judges head. Judge looked intently to ensure the back of his head was always to the TV viewers camera.

Answer (score 4):

As for the mistakes

> He was looking for mistakes in peoples haircuts and grooming. You never specify what type of mistakes the judge is looking for.

And the payment

> He recommends the barber to the athletes

Comment: It's cool, but their business is already concluded. The barber was compensated in full before the judge left the barber shop.

Comment: You might want to clarify that in your post as I took my answer to fulfill "Fully concluded ..." (as an agreement for referrals is an equitable conclusion) and "Never interact again". Maybe add the stipulation that "the barber was fully paid before the judge left the shop" at the end of your comment

Comment: That's an interesting interpretation of fully concluded =) but sure.

Answer (score 3):

The judge is judging a diving event. Competitive swimmers and divers shave their bodies to be more hydrodynamic. The judge lowers scores by looking more intently for mistakes, which makes contestants think they are performing poorly, and that they could do better getting shaved by the barber as a professional.

By doing this equally to all competitors, the judge feels like his is keeping the integrity of the competition.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be:

> The barber, supporting the local team, made a deal with the judge that, for each mistake by a foreign performer caught, he will deduct $1 equivalent from the debt?

Comment: Nope. Their business is entirely and satisfactorily concluded.

Comment: That would be illegal and dishonorable.

Comment: @PStag Please note that the Clarifications are added after most of the answers here are posted, thus question is marked as being *too broad*

Answer (score 0):

It rather sounds like the judge "paid" the barber by offering to exert bias against certain athletes by looking for mistakes in their routines more intently. Perhaps the barber has a favorite they'd like to see win, or is loyal to their national team, or has bets outstanding on an event.

Comment: I can assure you, the judge is beyond reproach, and the barber is a man who loves true competition more than winning. I like how you know it wasn't actually the answer, thus dodging the downvotes. =)

Comment: @corsiKa You should edit the question to include these further restrictions then. I suspect though that people will come up with answers other than what you intend but still fit the information given, as is prone to happen for riddles of the form "What did X do and why?"

Answer (score 0):

The judge was watching closely because:

> He wanted to minimize the total of the scores he gave.

This is because his deal with the barber was:

> The judge would pay the barber the total sum of the scores he gave to the participants.

Comment: Nope. Their business is entirely and satisfactorily concluded.

Comment: @corsiKa Ah. I see this requirement was edited in later.